# SQL search no duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I'm trying to learn the best way to perform a search.
I have 40 tables.  In the 40 tables All tables have 2 of the same column, ID and date; all the tables obviously have other columns that don't match.
Now not every table is used by the user.  A user could use 5 tables, they could use all 40.  Also the IDs could have multiple dates attached too them.  I would like to get ALL the dates from all 40 tables from an ID with no duplicates.  AKA if table 1 and table 10 have the same date I only want it 1 time.

So here I have some questions.

The first way I have read is this.

```
 $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT date FROM table1 
 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
 left joins for table2--->table40
 WHERE ID = ?
 GROUP BY date");
```

the second way I have seen is like this.

```
 $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Distinct date FROM table1 
 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
 left joins for table2--->table40
 WHERE ID = ?");
```

and the third way I have read is this. (their words not mine)
"In my experience (which is limited btw), I have used the equi join query for this purpose. Let me show you an example.

Consider three tables named Table1, Table2, and Table3 with a common column named Code(turned to ID). The code snippet below joins these three tables with no duplicates:"

```
 select date from Table1, Table2, Table3..... where Table1.ID=Table2.ID=Table3.ID......;
```

Now my question is what is the proper way for me to do this search??

It should return a list of dates found for 1 ID (the one being searched) no duplicates.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first and third approach differ only on syntax (first approach has a proper syntax, while the third one uses an archaic syntax that shouldn't be used for any new development for the last 15+ years).

All three approaches suffer from the same problem: when `Table1` does not have a target ID, presence or absence of that ID in other tables would not matter: you wouldn't get any dates from them unless `Table1` has the target ID.

You can fix this by using `UNION` on individual selects, like this:

```
SELECT date
FROM (
    SELECT date FROM Table1 WHERE Id=?
UNION
    SELECT date FROM Table2 WHERE Id=?
UNIO
    SELECT date FROM Table3 WHERE Id=?
UNION
    ...
UNION
    SELECT date FROM Table40 WHERE Id=?
) AS x
```

This would yield all `date` values regardless of the table in which it is found.

**Note:** An unfortunate side effect of this approach is the need to bind `Id` parameter forty times, because JDBC does not support named parameters.

Comment: Instead of using `Union ALL` and then eventually doing `Group By` to merge them into one; I feel that better approach would be simply using `Union`. It would remove all duplicates

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Right, that would do the same thing with less code. I am using `UNION ALL` + `GROUO BY` because I remember it being poorly optimized in one of the engines that I used 10+ years ago, but I am not sure if it is still relevant.

Comment: thank you, that clears things up for me.  I see the dilemma now that you pointed it out.  I didn't think about that prior.  It didn't occur to me that it would be an issue.   One question.  What is the AS for at the end?  I looked at examples https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp   as an understanding on how to do the union.  I was just curious if there is a reason to AS (which I understand as Alias) to the end of it?

Comment: @gtcode I added an alias to make the syntax compatible with other RDBMS engines which require an alias on a nested select. I don't think it's necessary on MySQL, but it's a good idea to keep it anyway in case you decide to migrate your project to SQL Server or another engine that requires an alias.

Comment: ok cool I will hit the w3schools and figure out how to add it.  thank you guys a bunch for helping to teach me.

Comment: @gtcode Aliasing on Derived Table is necessary on MySQL. "The [AS] tbl_name clause is mandatory because every table in a FROM clause must have a name." Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: @gtcode please dont use w3schools. Always prefer official docs on understanding how things work in actual.

Comment: cool i just book marked your link.  thanks for taking the time

Comment: there is something wrong with searching this way as it comes up empty.  I searched just 1 table and the PHP side gives a response on 1 table that is correct.  But when trying all these unions I get an empty reply on postman.  {
    "error": false,
    "message": "Data Aquired",
    "date": []
}   any ideas?

Comment: @gtcode That's not possible, there must be some other mistake somewhere else in your query.

Comment: finally got it to work.  I changed the column positions on the DB and it works now.  Not sure why it was that way but it finally works. thanks